# Comparing two object properties in JavaScript (codecademy course section)

Tags: javascript, html

I'm currently on CodeAcademy's javascript tutorials when i came across this lesson where i have to create a function which compares the ages of 2 people and outputs the age of the older person.In the case of both people being of equal age, it would then output the age.

Listed below is the code i have come up with.However, i keep getting an error in CodeAcademy's editor telling me that the older person is undefined. Could someone kindly steer me in the right direction and/or point out my mistake? thanks!

```
function Person(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}

var olderAge = function(person1, person2) {
    if (person1.age > person2.age) {
        console.log(person1.age);
    } else if (person1.age < person2.age) {
        console.log(person2.age);
    } else {
        console.log(person1.age);
    }
};

var alice = new Person("Alice", 30);
var billy = new Person("Billy", 25);

console.log(" The older person is " + olderAge(alice, billy));
```

Comment: You're not returning anything from olderAge function. If nothing is explicitly returned JavaScript will return undefined.

Comment: Replace console.log with return in the olderAge function

Comment: Ken, you're getting all the right answers here. I changed your question, the moderators are pretty harsh around here, maybe that'll help the down vote. Also, think of the console as a piece of scrap paper, and not so much part of the program. So when you log something to the console, you're asking the program that you're writing to simply spit out some value on scrap paper, so that you can be informed about what's going on in the program at that particular moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`olderAge` doesn't return anything

I think you might want to return the older person from that funciton.

so, instead of (or in addition to)

```
console.log(person1.age);
```

you want

```
return person1.name;
```

---

Or, you can change your call to

```
console.log(" The older person is "+ olderAge(alice, billy).name);
```

and then you can do

```
return person1;
```